# CKAN 2.0 - CSV/XLS files preview only with Dataproxy?

Tags: csv, xls, ckan

I have a problem with CKAN 2.0, just installed on a VirtualBox VM Ubuntu 12.04 64Bit.
I followed all steps of the official documentation but when I upload a file CSV into a dataset, the preview don't work because dataviewer use Dataproxy in place of Datastore.

My question is: CKAN 2.x uses only the dataproxy for prevew csv/xls files or I can use the datastore as in the previous versions? Reading here http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.0/data-viewer.html?highlight=datastore#viewing-structured-data-the-data-explorer is not clear if Datastore is used for all type of file or for all type except CSV/XLS.

Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the DataStore enabled and the data for that resource (data file) stored in the datastore then the datastore rather than the dataproxy will be used for the preview.

Think of the dataproxy as a fallback that kicks in if the DataStore is not enabled (or you have not stored that data file in the datastore).

Comment: Hi Rufus, thank's for your help. The problem is that I installed CKAN 2.0 by official documentation and datastore seems to be working ([here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/release-v2.0/datastore-setup.html#test-the-set-up) the curl command return the JSON page without errors). If I test the 2nd url instead, the error "ERROR [ckan.controllers.api] Can't find logic function: datastore_create" occurred. I have to install Datastorer too for 2.0 version?

Comment: This is very confusing. If the first curl command works then the datastore is installed and enabled. Are you sure you have no typos? Can you pastebin output of the first curl command and the 2nd one?

Comment: Hi Rufus, the output is too long to paste but seems to be correct. For the 2nd output please refear the previous comment. For your question about typos, I'm sure I pasted correctly the command to create the datastore how reported [here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.0/datastore-setup.html#test-the-set-up). Any ideas?